# How do I Modify the code snippet below ,so that if a page got a parent page the parent title/link is displayed instead in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_filter('avf_title_args', 'fix_page_title', 10, 1);
function fix_page_title($args) {

    $args['title'] = get_the_title();
    $args['link'] = get_permalink();

    return $args;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a parent using `$post->post_parent` and get the title using [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title):

```
add_filter('avf_title_args', 'fix_page_title', 10, 1);
function fix_page_title($args) {
    global $post;

    if($post->post_parent){
        $args['title'] = get_the_title();
    } else {
        $args['title'] = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
    }
    $args['link'] = get_permalink();

    return $args;

}
```

Or:

```
$args['title'] = get_the_title($post->post_parent ?: NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks George ,I got it :)